# ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I am facing a problem while creating a materialized view for our aggregations. If DML occurs on the source table, the materialized view should refresh automatically and show the updated results. The idea is to store the aggregation results and just fetch the numbers directly rather than doing a query, and I basically want to see if this meets our objective. Our table is going to have up to 3 million inserts a day.

As per the link [Example 8-3 Example 3: Creating a Materialized View](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm) I did:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON table WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
(SUBJECTID)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ih_data_aggregated_view
PARALLEL 
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT SUBJECTID ,count(*)as totalcount ,avg(price)as avgprice,sum(price) as totalprice
FROM table  
WHERE SUBJECTID='xxxxx'  GROUP by SUBJECTID;
```

but this gets:

> java.sql.SQLException: SQLException: ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view

Comment: Have you looked at [the restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#i1007028)?

Comment: "For each aggregate such as AVG(expr), the corresponding COUNT(expr) must be present.".
You should try changing `count(*)` for `count(price)`

Answer (score 3):

The documentation includes [general restrictions on materialised view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#i1007007) and on [materialised view with aggregates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#i1007028).

While working through those lists is instructive, you can see whether an existing or potential materialised view can be fast-refreshed by examining the results from[the `dbms_mview.explain_mview` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67191):

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  msg_array SYS.ExplainMVArrayType;
begin
  dbms_mview.explain_mview (q'[
SELECT SUBJECTID ,count(*)as totalcount ,avg(price)as avgprice,sum(price) as totalprice
FROM your_table
WHERE SUBJECTID='xxxxx'
GROUP by SUBJECTID
]',
     msg_array);
   for i in msg_array.first..msg_array.last loop
     dbms_output.put_line(rpad(msg_array(i).capability_name, 30)
       ||' '|| msg_array(i).possible
       ||' '|| msg_array(i).msgtxt);
  end loop;
end;
/

...
REFRESH_FAST                   F 
...
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      F agg(expr) requires correspondng COUNT(expr) function
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  F SUM(expr) without COUNT(expr)
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  F see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT is disabled
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML     F see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled
REFRESH_FAST_PCT               F PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables in the materialized view
...
```

As @vercelli mentioned, and as the `REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT` message suggests, you need to change `count(*)` to `count(price)`. But that isn't the whole story; if you just change that you'll see:

```
REFRESH_FAST                   F 
...
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      F mv log does not have all necessary columns
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  F see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT is disabled
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  F COUNT(*) is not present in the select list
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML     F see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled
```

Your materialised view log has to include the column you are aggregating:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON your_table WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
(SUBJECTID,PRICE)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

Materialized view LOG created.

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ih_data_aggregated_view
PARALLEL 
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT SUBJECTID ,count(price)as totalcount ,avg(price)as avgprice,sum(price) as totalprice
FROM your_table
WHERE SUBJECTID='xxxxx'
GROUP by SUBJECTID;

Materialized view IH_DATA_AGGREGATED_VIEW created.
```

The missing `count(*)` is still reported but as this is against a single table it isn't preventing fast refresh. It's worth noting that if your `price` column is nullable then `count(price)` and `count(*)` may give different results; if that is the case you might want to get both counts as columns in your MV anyway.

Comment: Hi Alex Thanks for wirting the detailed answer.I am still facing the same issue. The REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT capability says it better: mv log does not have all necessary columns.When I execute your procedure it shows me REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      F mv log does not have all necessary columns.I created the views using queries you mentioned.Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @MrWayne - you recreated the MV log to include the price column too?

Comment: yes I did.Exact command I followed to create the MV on LOG CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON PR_DATA_IH_FACT_MILLION WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID (SUBJECTID,PRICE) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

Comment: rror report:
SQL Error: ORA-12033: cannot use filter columns from materialized view log on "TE_6051"."PR_DATA_IH_FACT_MILLION"
12033. 0000 -  "cannot use filter columns from materialized view log on \"%s\".\"%s\""
*Cause:    The materialized view log either did not have filter columns
           logged, or the timestamp associated with the filter columns was
           more recent than the last refresh time.
*Action:   A complete refresh is required before the next fast refresh.
           Add filter columns to the materialized view log, if required.

Comment: Then that suggests your MV is referencing other columns you haven't mentioned - not just subjectid and price. Any column you refer to in the MV query has to be included in the MV log.